# Workflow when using templates

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have made my index page and then made that my template. I use the template to create more HTML pages with a similar look, though different content in the middle. Should I make my index page be based on the template, so when I edit in the template, it is also update on the index?

If I don't do this, I have to do everything twice. My question is; what is the best workflow when using templates in Dreamweaver like this?

Comment: I use DW mostly for WebDAV support and code view (only), so I'm not a DW "pro" as it were, but in most cases a scripting language like PHP would handle this situation. MVC is the particular pattern/approach developed to handle this by most frameworks like CodeIgniter. Are you using a system, or just flat files?

Comment: The Symfony docs has a decent way of [demonstrating a simple to Symfony way](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) of doing this type of setup, btw. Their template system is [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), and you might be interested in [Twig for Template Designers](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html).